# DX11 Compute Shader writes only to one index

Tags: c++, hlsl, directcompute

I really can't figure out what's going on here.

I have a compute shader that takes in an FFT result (from real input) and computes the powers of each bin, storing them in a different buffer (UAV).  The FFT implementation is that of the D3DCSX library.

The shader in question:

```
struct Complex {
    float real;
    float imag;
};

RWStructuredBuffer<Complex> g_result : register(u0);
RWStructuredBuffer<float> g_powers : register(u1);

[numthreads(1, 1, 1)] void main(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID) {
    const uint  bin  = id.x;
    const float real = g_result[bin + 1].real;
    const float imag = g_result[bin + 1].imag;

    const float power = real * real + imag * imag;
    const float mag = sqrt(power);
    const float db = 10.0f * log10(1.0f + power);

    g_powers[bin] = power;
}
```

The buffer creation code:

```
//The buffer in which the resulting powers are stored (m_result_buffer1)
buffer_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
buffer_desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(float) * NumBins();
buffer_desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
buffer_desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_ALLOW_RAW_VIEWS;
buffer_desc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(float);
buffer_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

hr = m_device->CreateBuffer (
    &buffer_desc,
    nullptr,
    &m_result_buffer1
); HR_THROW();

//UAV for m_result_buffer1
view_desc.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
view_desc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
view_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS;
view_desc.Buffer.Flags = D3D11_BUFFER_UAV_FLAG_RAW;
view_desc.Buffer.NumElements = NumBins();

hr = m_device->CreateUnorderedAccessView (
    m_result_buffer1,
    &view_desc,
    &m_result_view
); HR_THROW();

//Buffer for reading powers to the CPU
buffer_desc.BindFlags = 0;
buffer_desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(float) * NumBins();
buffer_desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
buffer_desc.MiscFlags = 0;
buffer_desc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(float);
buffer_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;

hr = m_device->CreateBuffer (
    &buffer_desc,
    nullptr,
    &m_result_buffer2
); HR_THROW();
```

The dispatch code:

```
CComPtr<ID3D11UnorderedAccessView> result_view;

hr = m_fft->ForwardTransform (
    m_sample_view,
    &result_view
); HR_THROW();

ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* views[] = {
    result_view,  //FFT UAV   (u0)
    m_result_view //Power UAV (u1)
};

m_context->CSSetShader(m_power_cs, nullptr, 0);
m_context->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 2, views, nullptr);
m_context->Dispatch(NumBins(), 1, 1);
```

And finally the CPU mapping code:

```
m_context->CopyResource(m_result_buffer2, m_result_buffer1);

D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE sub = { 0 };

m_context->Map(m_result_buffer2, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &sub);
memcpy(result, sub.pData, sizeof(float) * NumBins());
m_context->Unmap(m_result_buffer2, 0);
```

What happens is this shader appears to have every thread write to the same index in the output buffer.  The mapped buffer always reads a correct value for the first bin, then 0.0f for every other bin.  The equivalent code on the CPU runs just fine.  What's weird is I've placed conditionals and know that `bin` is not just 0 all the time, and that the power of every bin outside bin 0 is also not always 0.0f.  I've also tried writing to multiple bins on the same thread using a for loop, and the same thing happens.  What am I doing wrong?

I have a hunch that it's the buffer creation code or mapping code that's at the root of the problem.  I know I'm running the correct number of threads on the GPU and that the dispatch ID's are correct, it's the CPU-side result that's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

I was using a `RWStructuredBuffer` to represent a `RWByteOrderBuffer`.  Not entirely sure how that led to this result, but it did.  So, the FFT result is now a `RWByteOrderBuffer`.  What was strange about this buffer, though, was the fact that the D3DCSX implementation spaced the float values so far apart - possibly for cache reasons, but I'm honestly not too sure why.  This is my compute shader now (computing decibels instead of powers this time - an unrelated change):

```
RWByteAddressBuffer       g_result   : register(u0);
RWStructuredBuffer<float> g_decibels : register(u1);

[numthreads(256, 1, 1)] void main(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID) {
    const float real = asfloat(g_result.Load(id.x * 8 + 0));
    const float imag = asfloat(g_result.Load(id.x * 8 + 4));

    const float power = real * real + imag * imag;
    const float db = 10.0f * log10(1.0f + power);

    g_decibels[id.x] = db;
}
```

I changed my decibel buffer's description to that of a structured buffer, though, just to make things easier for me:

```
buffer_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
buffer_desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(float) * NumBins();
buffer_desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
buffer_desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED;
buffer_desc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(float);
buffer_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

hr = m_device->CreateBuffer (
    &buffer_desc,
    nullptr,
    &m_result_buffer1
); HR_THROW();

view_desc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
view_desc.Buffer.Flags = 0;
view_desc.Buffer.NumElements = NumBins();
view_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
view_desc.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;

hr = m_device->CreateUnorderedAccessView (
    m_result_buffer1,
    &view_desc,
    &m_result_view
); HR_THROW();
```

This is why `g_decibels` is still a `RWStructuredBuffer`.

Still unknown to me is whether or not it matters that the result buffer is read/write when only accesses are necessary - if I change `g_result` to a regular `ByteOrderBuffer` I get no output.  But at least it's working now.